# Images with AIML Chatbot in Android Studio

Tags: android, chatbot, aiml

I was developing the chatbot aiml with pandorabots, testing the aiml files in android studio, a lot of tags don't work such as the delay, buttons, image and others 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzl2Q.png)

I guess these only work in pandorabots if I were to make it an api call but that's not the subject.

I'd like to know how to at least get images from my chatbot with basic aiml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your AIML interpreter supports HTML tags, you can display an image using this syntax:

```
<category>
    <pattern>SHOW ME A SANDWICH</pattern>
    <template>
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VNQrhX4/sandwich1.jpg"></img>
    </template>
</category>
```